# entity framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I' ve got tables: Customer, Order, Product

Customer has gor a lot of orders, each order has got a lot wof products.

How can I write query to get all products from Customer ?
I need to use it as a datasource, thanks for help
bye

Comment: Write a stored procedure for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var products = from customer in customers
               from order in customer.Orders
               from product in order.Products
               select product;
```

Just use LINQ SelectMany.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var result = customer
                .SelectMany(x=>x.Orders)
                .Select(x=>x.Products)
```

Also you can add .Distinct() to retrieve only different products

Another way is to go from Products:

```
var result = dbContext.Products
                .Where(x=>x.Orders.Any(o=>o.Customer.Id == customer.Id))
```

Hard to read and hard to understand, but still works)